# update a table using trigger after delete and update

Tags: sql-server, triggers

In my website I show a list of names and their comment count. I was doing it like:

```
select * 
from names, (select count(id) from comments where nid = names.id) comment_count
```

Now I want to add a `comment_count` column to my names table and omit retrieving count. as each comment needs to be confirmed and and my confirm command either deletes comment (if it is not suitable) or updates its confirmed flag to 1, I'm trying to do this:

```
create trigger change_comment_count 
on comments after update,delete
as 
   if exists(select id from deleted)
      update names 
      set comment_count = (select count(id) 
                           from comments 
                           where nid in (select nid from deleted d) 
                             and confirmed = 1) 
      where id = d.nid
else
    if exists(select id from updated)
       update names 
       set comment_count = (select count(id) 
                            from comments 
                            where nid in (select nid from deleted d) 
                              and confirmed = 1) 
       where id = d.nid
```

but I'm getting an error:

> The multi-part identifier "d.nid" could not be bound.

Comment: Why are you doing this? Is the query performing poorly?

Comment: @marc_s could you please suggest how to do it?

Comment: @MarceloCantos besides comment count,I have image count, question count,... and yes it is effecting performance so I'm trying to do this for comments, images, question, votes,...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all - there is no `updated` pseudo table in SQL Server; in the case of an `UPDATE` operation, `deleted` will contain the old values, while `Inserted` will contain the new ones.

Secondly: in both cases, you're **not** referring to `deleted AS d` in your `UPDATE` statement anywhere - so of course you cannot reference `d.nid` - there is no alias `d` in that scope

Since in both the `DELETE` and the `UPDATE` case, you will have entries in the `Deleted` pseudo table, that's really all you need to look at - all affected rows in the `dbo.Names` table need to be updated.

Try something like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER change_comment_count 
ON dbo.Comments 
AFTER UPDATE,DELETE
AS 
    UPDATE dbo.Names 
    SET comment_count = (SELECT COUNT(c.id) 
                         FROM dbo.Comments c 
                         INNER JOIN Deleted d ON c.nid = d.nid
                         WHERE c.confirmed = 1) 
    FROM deleted d                             
    WHERE dbo.Names.id = d.nid
```

So I'm just doing an `INNER JOIN` between the `dbo.Names` and the `Deleted` tables which gives me all rows in `dbo.Names` that were either updated or deleted.

The `COUNT(id)` can also be simplified by using an `INNER JOIN` between the `dbo.Comments` table and the `Deleted` pseudo table.